# How to decode C++ Google Protocol Buffers WriteVarint32 from Python

Tags: python, c++, sockets, serialization, protocol-buffers

Right now we are working on a multiplayer game with a client in python and a server in C++.

We send the size of the header, a header with an object Id and the object. When parsing, we read the size of the header, parse the header and then start parsing the object it indicates. Everything works fine until I try to send a response from C++ to the python client, then _DecodeVarInt32 reads only a byte and determines that the size of the header is 0.

We suspect its because of the int encoding, but we haven't found any material regarding this issue and protocol buffers

Socket send on C++

```
int sz = header.size()+4+obj.size();

char* pkg = new char[sz];
google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream aos(pkg,sz);
CodedOutputStream *cos= new CodedOutputStream(&aos);
cos->WriteVarint32(header.size());
cos->WriteString(header.data());
cos->WriteString(obj.data());

int rc = sendto(sd,(void*)pkg,sz,0,&sock.sa,sock.sa_len);
```

Socket receive in C++

```
google::protobuf::uint32 sz;
google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream ais(buffer,MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
CodedInputStream cis(&ais);
cis.ReadVarint32(&sz);
auto lim = cis.PushLimit(sz);
sample.from_bin(cis);
cis.PopLimit(lim);
obj.from_bin(cis);
```

Socket send on python

```
    header = Header(headerId)
    header.to_bin()
    object.to_bin()

    headerSize = _VarintBytes(header._size)

    print(len(headerSize))
    print(header._size)
    print(object._size)
    
    btarray = headerSize + header._data + object._data
    
    print(len(btarray))
    self.sock.sendto(btarray,(self.host,self.port))
```

And socket receive in python

```
def recvHeader(self):
    buf = self.sock.recv(2000,socket.MSG_PEEK)
    print(buf)
    rc = Header(serialMsg.MessageID.LOGINPETITION)
    n = 0
    hdSize, n =_DecodeVarint32(buf,n)
    rc.from_bin(buf[n:n+hdSize])
    n+=hdSize
    return (rc,n)

def loadObject(self,object,startPos):
    print('start load')
    buf = self.sock.recv(2000)
    object.from_bin(buf[startPos:])
    print('loaded')
```